# To find the different line-ups the team can make.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $9$ different positions in baseball team, and the team has $16$ players. To find the different line-ups the team can make.

My solution is $$16P9 = \frac{16!}{(16-9)!}$$

Is the solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the order of the lineup matters, but in baseball it usually does (batting order, field positions). In which case, yeah, you're right!